# Creating a gallery by parsing a webpage for meta data

Tags: android

I am trying to retrieve some image URLs and image texts by scraping a website when my app starts up. I then want to use arrays I've created of imageTexts and imageURLs to create a ViewPager so I can display the images as a scrollable gallery.

I execute the network task of fetching the webpage and parsing the HTML as an AsyncTask (downloadTask() in the code below).

My problem is that as this happens in the background it doesn't have time to fetch and parse the data before the code tries to display the images. I get a null pointer error when the code hits

> new ViewPagerAdapter(this, getimageText(), getimageURLS())

I can deduce that the array that should eventually store the image URLs and the image Texts hasn't been created yet. This is at the point my app crashes.

Here's my code. I'm new to both Android and Java so clearly I could do with a lot of help!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from viewpager_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main);

        // Fetch the list of URLs using a background network task
        new downloadTask().execute(BASE_URL);

        // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, getimageText(), getimageURLS());

        // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can initially set a default image and you can modify your asyncTask to take in a callback method. This callback method would be a method that initializes your ViewPager. In your AsyncTask you would get the images and override the onPostExecute() method to call that callback method.

Example

```
class PictureGrabber extends AsyncTask<URL, VOID, VOID>{
IPicCallBack callBack;
PictureGrabber(IPicCallBack callback)
{
    this.callback = callback;
}

protected Void doInBackGround(URL... urls){
}

protected void onPostExecute(VOID result)
{
    callback.Init();
}

public interface IPicCallBack{
    public void Init();
}
```

Then in your code you need to implement that IPicCallback and set it on the asyncTask and when the task is complete it'll call that method

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up taking a step back and approaching it from a different angle. Instead of putting a call back in the postExecute I put the View Pager intialisation code there. The inBackground task calls this after it completes anyway so I didn't see the need for the call back. Thank you for your suggestion though. It made me read around a bit more which gave me clarity.

Comment: Sounds good. The only thing though is that with that callback you can keep all instantiation code in one place, instead of having it spread all over your code.